# Why isn't gatsby-transformer-remark adding IDs to headings so that I could link to them?

Tags: markdown, gatsby

I believe(d) that gatsby-transformer-remark automatically adds IDs to each heading so that you can link to them. Its `tableOfContents` generates links to such IDs yet my headings do not have them. Why? It should work as it does here https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/hello-world-kitchen-sink/ (which also adds gatsby-remark-autolink-headers for fancy effects).

See an example here https://blog.jakubholy.net/it-will-only-take-1h/, the code is at https://github.com/holyjak/blog.jakubholy.net

Thank you!

Comment: Adding IDs to headings is not standard Markdown behavior. I'm not personally familiar with gatsby, but have you checked for a config option or extension which enables the feature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> gatsby-transformer-remark automatically adds IDs to each heading

It doesn't, it's solely the work of [`gatsby-remark-autolink-headers`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-remark-autolink-headers). Autolink-headers is not only there for fancy effect, it actually generates the id for each header using [`github-slugger`](https://github.com/Flet/github-slugger).

You can see the implementation detail [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/94a80b798d50f03f60e560946cec57ff9e1bc3d4/packages/gatsby-remark-autolink-headers/src/index.js#L22)

Comment: Also, remember to place it in your gatsby-transformer-remark plugin array at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [gatsby-remark-heading-slug](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-heading-slug/) plugin which uses [github-slugger](https://github.com/Flet/github-slugger) to add IDs for you without any of the additional complexity of [gatsby-remark-autolink-headers](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-autolink-headers/).